# ¿porque al intentar abrir mi documento de excel (generado por un Jtable) me marca error?

Tags: java

Al darle click en exportar se supone que se genera un excel con los datos de el Jframe el problema es que al abrir el Excel me marca error diciendo que el formato o la extencion esta mal

Este es el código:

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout; 
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Desktop;
    import java.awt.List;
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.Vector;
    import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    import javax.swing.JTable;
    import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
    import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
    import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
    import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
    import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
    import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;
    import javax.swing.text.TableView.TableRow;

    import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
    import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
    import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
    import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
    import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.util.SheetUtil;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

    import java.io.DataOutputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;


    public class Tabla {

    private JTable t;
    private static DefaultTableModel m;
    private TableRow r;
    private int i=0;
    private int a=0;
    private List nom_files;
    private File file;

    public Tabla(){

    //* Inicializar variables *//
    JFrame v = new JFrame();
    m = new DefaultTableModel();
    t = new JTable(m);
    t = new JTable(m);
    t.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    JScrollPane s = new JScrollPane(t);
    JScrollPane s1 = new JScrollPane(t);
    s1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    s1.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    //datos
    m.addColumn("INDICADORES");
    m.addColumn("Desarrollo Social");
    m.addColumn("Recursos materiales");
    m.addColumn("Des.agropecuario");
    m.addColumn("Desarrollo economico");
    m.addColumn("Educacion y cultura");
    m.addColumn("Seguridad Publica");
    m.addColumn(" DIF");
    m.addColumn("Secretaria general");
    m.addColumn("Archivo");
    m.addColumn("Registro de lo familiar");
    m.addColumn("Catastro");
    m.addColumn("Turismo");
    m.addColumn("Transparencia");
    m.addColumn("Informatica");
    m.addColumn("Teseroria");
    m.addColumn("Contraloria");
    m.addColumn("Conciliacion Municipal");
    m.addColumn("Servicios generales");
    m.addColumn("Ecologia");
    m.addColumn("Reaglamentos y Espect");
    m.addColumn("Obras publicas");
    m.addColumn("Planeacion");
    m.addColumn("Comunicacion social");
    m.addColumn("IMDM");
    m.addColumn("IMJUV");
    m.addColumn("COMUDE");
    m.addColumn("Poteccion civil");

    m.addRow(new Object[]{"Informe mensual de los avances de POA.",});
    m.addRow(new Object[]{"Entrega puntual del reporte mensual."});
    m.addRow(new Object[]{"No tener Ausencia de su personal de ningun tipo."});
    m.addRow(new Object[]{"Cumplimiento de uninforme institucional completo."});
    m.addRow(new Object[]{"Asistencia a reuniones que sean de caracter obligatorio."});
    m.addRow(new Object[]{"Cumplimiento de comisiones"});
    m.addRow(new Object[]{"No contar con ningun tipo de quejas o notas negativas"});
    m.addRow(new Object[]{"Cumplir con los indicadores de la ADM."});
    m.addRow(new Object[]{"Cumplir en tiempo y forma sus declaraciones patrimoniales."});
    m.addRow(new Object[]{"Cumplir con las evaluacionesdel sistema de control interno"});
    m.addRow(new Object[]{"Cumplimiento con los procesos de salida"});
    m.addRow(new Object[]{"Entrega de informacion en tiempo y forma."});
    m.addRow(new Object[]{"No tener ningun tipo de observacion."});
    m.addRow(new Object[]{"Cumplir con los indicadores de PBR."});
    m.addRow(new Object[]{"Mantener su area limpia y ordenada."});
    m.addRow(new Object[]{"No comer dentro de las areas exepto en cumpleaños."});
    m.addRow(new Object[]{"Guardar orden y respeto en las areas."});
    m.addRow(new Object[]{"Mantenerse en su area de servicio  ya que seran supervisados."});
    m.addRow(new Object[]{"Cumplimiento del reglamentointerno de trabajo."});
    //datos

    //Diseño
    t.setSelectionForeground( Color.white );
    t.setSelectionBackground( Color.RED );
    v.getContentPane().add(s1,BorderLayout.CENTER);



    JPanel pN=new JPanel();
    JButton aF = new JButton("Agregar indicador");
    pN.add(aF);
    aF.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    agregar(1);
    } 
    });

    JButton bF = new JButton("Eliminar indicador");
    pN.add(bF);
    bF.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    eliminar(2);
    } 
    });
    JButton aC = new JButton("Agrear departamento");
    pN.add(aC);
    aC.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    agregar(2);
    }
    });
    JButton bC = new JButton("Eliminar departamento");
    pN.add(bC);
    bC.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    eliminar(1);
    }
    });

    JButton ex = new JButton("Exportar");
    pN.add(ex);
    ex.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Exportar();
        }

    private void Exportar() {
        JFileChooser seleccionar = new JFileChooser();
        File archivo;
        if (seleccionar.showDialog(null, "Exportar a Excel") == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            archivo = seleccionar.getSelectedFile();
            int cantFila = m.getRowCount();
            int cantColumna = m.getColumnCount();
            HSSFWorkbook wb;
            wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
            Sheet hoja = ((org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook) wb).createSheet(" ");

            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < cantFila; i++) {
                    Row fila = hoja.createRow(i + 1);
                    for (int j = 0; j < cantColumna; j++) {
                        Cell celda = fila.createCell(j);
                        if (i == -1) {
                            celda.setCellValue(String.valueOf(m.getColumnName(j)));
                        } else {
                            celda.setCellValue(String.valueOf(m.getValueAt(i, j)));
                        }
                        wb.write(new FileOutputStream(archivo + ".xlsx"));
                    }
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exportacion exitosa");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Vuelve a intentarlo");
            }
        }
    }
    });


    //Diseño
    TableColumnModel columnModel = t.getColumnModel();
    columnModel.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(420);
    columnModel.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(130);
    columnModel.getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(150);
    columnModel.getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(130);
    columnModel.getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(140);
    columnModel.getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(130);
    columnModel.getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(130);
    columnModel.getColumn(7).setPreferredWidth(90);
    columnModel.getColumn(8).setPreferredWidth(150);
    columnModel.getColumn(9).setPreferredWidth(100);
    columnModel.getColumn(10).setPreferredWidth(150);
    columnModel.getColumn(11).setPreferredWidth(100);
    columnModel.getColumn(12).setPreferredWidth(100);
    columnModel.getColumn(13).setPreferredWidth(130);
    columnModel.getColumn(14).setPreferredWidth(120);
    columnModel.getColumn(15).setPreferredWidth(120);
    columnModel.getColumn(16).setPreferredWidth(120);
    columnModel.getColumn(17).setPreferredWidth(140);
    columnModel.getColumn(18).setPreferredWidth(150);
    columnModel.getColumn(19).setPreferredWidth(130);
    columnModel.getColumn(20).setPreferredWidth(150);
    columnModel.getColumn(21).setPreferredWidth(130);
    columnModel.getColumn(22).setPreferredWidth(120);
    columnModel.getColumn(23).setPreferredWidth(140);
    columnModel.getColumn(24).setPreferredWidth(100);
    columnModel.getColumn(25).setPreferredWidth(100);
    columnModel.getColumn(26).setPreferredWidth(100);
    columnModel.getColumn(27).setPreferredWidth(140);
    v.getContentPane().add(pN,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    v.pack();
    v.setBounds(-10,-8,8000,745);
    v.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    v.setVisible(true);
    t.setVisible(true);
    t.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 15)); 
    }



    protected static int getRowCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }



    private void eliminar(int caso){
    try{
    switch(caso){
    case 1:
    t.removeColumn(t.getColumnModel().getColumn(t.getSelectedColumn()));
    break;
    case 2:
    m.removeRow(t.getSelectedRow());
    break;
    }
    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aIE){}
    }


    private void agregar(int caso){
    try{
    switch(caso){
    case 1:
    m.addRow(new Object[]{a++,"",""});
    break;
    case 2:
    m.addColumn(i++);
    break;
    } 
    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aIE){}
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
    new Tabla();

            }
        }
```

y el error supongo que esta en esta parte:

```
    private void Exportar() {
        JFileChooser seleccionar = new JFileChooser();
        File archivo;
        if (seleccionar.showDialog(null, "Exportar a Excel") == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            archivo = seleccionar.getSelectedFile();
            int cantFila = m.getRowCount();
            int cantColumna = m.getColumnCount();
            HSSFWorkbook wb;
            wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
            Sheet hoja = ((org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook) wb).createSheet(" ");

            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < cantFila; i++) {
                    Row fila = hoja.createRow(i + 1);
                    for (int j = 0; j < cantColumna; j++) {
                        Cell celda = fila.createCell(j);
                        if (i == -1) {
                            celda.setCellValue(String.valueOf(m.getColumnName(j)));
                        } else {
                            celda.setCellValue(String.valueOf(m.getValueAt(i, j)));
                        }
                        wb.write(new FileOutputStream(archivo + ".xlsx"));
                    }
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exportacion exitosa");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Vuelve a intentarlo");
            }
        }
    }
    });
```

Comment: Hola Nataly es importante seas especifica cuando preguntes, en este caso agrega cual es el error, es importante esta información, **como anteriormente se te sugirió revisa [ask] para que modifiques tu pregunta y obtengas buenas respuestas, no realices la misma pregunta una y otra vez mejor realiza una de acuerdo al documento que te compartimos, nuevamente te invitamos a realizar el [tour] del sitio**, saludos!

Comment: organice bien el codigo y asi le ayudamos , para eso seleccione todo y presione Ctrl +K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que funcione de esa manera, cambia el formato de la extension de

```
wb.write(new FileOutputStream(archivo + ".xlsx"));
```

a

```
wb.write(new FileOutputStream(archivo + ".xls"));
```

de esta manera funciono en mi compilacion.

Saludos.

Comment: ya lo abre pero no como en el Jframe

Comment: Como te aparece? Te aparecen null en los elementos que estan vacios? Ahi vas a tener que hacer el parseo de los datos, o que se inicialicen con una cadena vacia cada elemento de las columnas.

Comment: si aparece eso pero aparte no me da los titulos de las columnas

Comment: Creo que es por que utilizas la comparacion    `if (i == -1)` a mi parecer nunca va a tener ese valor. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]***> El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada.***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
La excepción es de tipo FileNotFoundException.

En File archivo puse:

File archivo= new File("C:\Users\USUARIO\Documents");

Y me lo guardo.